# Spring Boot app to integrate Kafka with JMS

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, jms, spring-kafka

I'm trying to build a Spring Boot app that reads messages from Kafka and sends them via JMS and vice versa (read from JMS and write to kafka). However, I didn't find any useful tutorial to jumpstart my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Spring Integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration) and the [Spring Integration Extension for Apache Kafka](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-integration).

Use inbound and outbound channel adapters

```
jms -> kafka

kafka -> jms
```

Kafka Connect also has some capabilities in this space, but I am not familiar with it.

**EDIT**

This simple Spring Boot app shows transferring data from Kafka to RabbitMQ and vice versa:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.QueueBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.TopicBuilder;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class So61069735Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61069735Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner toKafka() {
        return args -> this.kafkaTemplate.send("so61069735-1", "foo");
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so61069735-1", topics = "so61069735-1")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        System.out.println("From Kafka: " + in);
        this.rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("so61069735-2", in.toUpperCase());
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so61069735-2")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println("From Rabbit: " + in);
        this.kafkaTemplate.send("so61069735-3", in + in);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so61069735-3", topics = "so61069735-3")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println("Final: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so61069735-1").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return QueueBuilder.durable("so61069735-2").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so61069735-3").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

Result

```
From Kafka: foo
From Rabbit: FOO
Final: FOOFOO
```

Comment: is there any other way ? (without the use of spring integration)

Comment: You can do it directly with a combination of spring-kafka and spring-jms and, as I said, Kafka Connect is another option.

Comment: could you be more precise about the solution involving the combination of spring-kafka and spring-jms.Could you send me exemples

Comment: I added an example.